# javascript for loop doesn't loop through the end

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an Array of Objects which should be placed on a FabricJS Canvas.
I iterate over the Array, look at what Canvas the Object should be placed on, create the canvas if it doesn't exist and place the object there. It works fine with text and geometrical shapes but Images it places on the last Slide.
When I debug it breaks on the Line "fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function(oImg){" and goes to the next iteration.

```
function dataIsLoaded(){
    for (var i=0; i<myObj.objects.length; i++){
        var slideIndex= myObj.objects[i].canvas;
        try{
            var canvas = document.getElementById('slide_'+slideIndex).fabric;
        } catch(e){     
            createCanvas(slideIndex);
            var canvas = document.getElementById('slide_'+slideIndex).fabric;
        }       
        var type= myObj.objects[i].type;
        if(type =="image"){
            var src = myObj.objects[i].src;
            var top = myObj.objects[i].top;
            var left = myObj.objects[i].left;
            var angle = myObj.objects[i].angle;
            var scaleX = myObj.objects[i].scaleX;
            var scaleY = myObj.objects[i].scaleY;
            fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function(oImg){
                oImg.set({
                    left: left, 
                    top: top, 
                    angle: angle,
                    scaleX: scaleX,
                    scaleY:scaleY           
                });
                canvas.add(oImg);

            });         
        }
    }
}
```

And myObj looks like:

```
var myObj ={
    'objects': [
        {
            'type': 'image',
            'canvas': '0',
            'src': 'file:///D:/Flyingblocks/designer/4.png',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'angle': 0,
            'originX': 'left',
            'originY': 'top',
            'scaleX': 1.50195,
            'scaleY': 1.50195
        },{
        'type': 'text',
        'text': 'Hallo',
        'canvas': '1',
        'top': 221,
        'left': 162,
        'angle': 0,
        'scaleX': 1,
        'scaleY': 1,
        'originX': 'left',
        'originY': 'top',
        'fill': 'rgba(0,0,0,1.0)',
        'fontFamily': 'Aharoni',
        'fontSize': 40
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: By the time the callback is invoked, the loop is already on its second iteration and the values of `left` etc. have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not load any local image or file in javascript, there will be [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem.
you can give any live URL of any image and that will work